# How to externalize rest-messages.properties in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

Is it possible to externalize `rest-messages.properties` in SDR?
I tried to move it to `./config` folder, for example, but it didn't work.

Comment: It takes about 5 sseconds to google that and find the answer : [src/main/resources/rest-default-messages.properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/resources/rest-default-messages.properties)

Comment: I know about it

Answer (score 0):

The rest-messages.properties (used to add custom details to your [ALPS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps) descriptions) goes to the same location where you would put custom application-`*`.properties or messages-`*`.properties file.

For instance, for a Spring Boot project the .properties file are located in the src/main/resources/ directory.

You can also set [custom config locations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) for your .properties file.

Edit after the OP's comment: However, I tried using a custom rest-messages.properties outside of the project .jar (as I usually do with my application.properties), and it does not seem to work.

Comment: I did not ask about how to use rest-messages.properties (I already use it now). I asked how to externalize it (like [externalizing Spring Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)).

Comment: My bad. Could you edit the question to avoid the confusion? I'll look into it in the mean time.

Comment: What confuses in my question? I asked "How to **externalize** rest-messages.properties?". Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Not at all, but since I got confused, other people may, as I did, read the question to fast and get it wrong. Regarding your question itself, I tried using an external rest-messages.properties as I would use an external application.properties, and it seems like it does not work. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wrote about it: "I tried to move it to ./config folder, for example, but it didn't work"...

Comment: Dude, let's not fight about it. I already admitted my mistake, and basically I was just trying to help you.

Comment: I don't 'fight' )) I just pointed that I also try it...

I think that @OliverGierke forgot about externalizing `rest-messages.properties` in SDR.. ((

Comment: You should open a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST/) ticket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136243/discussion-between-marc-tarin-and-cepr0).